# Issue with a:hover on dropdown menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu with two columns and I want the links inside the block that is the dropdown to change color when hovered over but when I add the style only the top level `ul` elements work and the entire block is active.  I have been looking at this thing too long and can't figure out where I need to add the `a:hover` for the `li`.

Any idea where I need to place it so that the main links don't have a hover effect and the dropdown level do?

[Full Screen](http://ttac.gmu.edu/test/ttac_home)

[jsFiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/jricharc/LYhSg/)

Answer (score 2):

This will make it work:

```
#top_nav li:hover > a { ... }
```

So, only the anchor directly within the hovered LI element "becomes active". When you hover the "projects" top-level menu item, its anchor will change color, but the anchors in the drop-down menu won't. When you then hover one of the anchors in that drop-down menu, it will change color, since *its* containing LI element has been hovered.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much.  I was just missing the > my brain is fried today!  Thanks so much again!!